# Error al generar PDF enviando dato por método GET

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, post, get

estoy tratando de generar un reporte PDF que recaba información de una tabla con datos, esta tabla contiene un campo llamado PIN. La situación es que tengo un panel de administración donde tengo mostrados registros de otra tabla y estos registros igual tienen un campo llamado PIN que corresponde a mi tabla de datos de donde extraigo la info para el generar el PDF.

El problema es que al tratar de generar PDF este envía el PIN seleccionado por método GETa la url del archivo que genera el PDF pero **NO LO GENERA** a pesar de que si envía por url el PIN la página se queda en blanco. 
Agradezco su ayuda.

Código de Botón que envía el PIN del cual se quiere generar el PDF.

```
 <?php echo "<td><a href='generarReporte.php?pin=".$row['pin']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='far fa-file-pdf' color='white'></i></button></a></td>";?>
```

Código que genera el PDF:

```
<?php  
function fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY pin ASC";   
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{      
$output .= 'TODO EL CONTENIDO HTML DEL PDF CONSULTADO CON EL DATO "PIN"';  
}  
return $output; 
}  
if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
{  
require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');
//PROPIEDADES DEL PDF
}  
<?
```

Comment: Puedes usar `print_r($sql)` para ver si el query esta bien estructurado

Comment: @JonathanOrta acabo de verificar y me resulta la estructura, el problema considero es el envío del dato mediante GET al programa del archivo, si se envía ya hasta lo imprimí con echo $_get['pin'] y si lo imprimió.

Comment: @JonathanOrta de igual manera consideraba un error en el if de salida despues de cerrar $output; que es generado como $_POST e intente cambiandolo por $_GET y no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problema de la siguiente forma:

Primero, metí el botón a una etiqueta form utilizando el método POST para transferir el dato al programa PDF y recibirlo por método GET.

```
<?php echo "<td><form action='reportesCuestionariosAdmin.php?pin=".$row['pin']."' method='POST'> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='generate_pdf'><i class='far fa-file-pdf' color='white'></i></button></form></td>";?>
```

Una vez transferido el dato se recíbe por metodo GET y se realiza la consulta para generar nuestro archivo PDF.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM texto_menos50 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY T.pin ASC";
```